# How To crawl my websites every products with Category on google

Tags: web-crawler, seo, xml-sitemap

I am new in SEO things! and I want to create Google search result better for my PHP based website's every product.

I have around 8,00,000 to 10,00,000 lac products in my website & 90-100 categories.

Now I want to create SEO for all products, so Google can crawl my products easily.

So please help me for how to create site map for this much products and how to inform to Google for crawl my sitemap?

Comment: this question should be asked in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an account for your site in [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).
2. Create an *XML sitemap* for your site. You can use one of free tools that can be Googled easily.
3. Submit your *sitemap.xml* to your GWMT account.